# Running a resource-hungry application on the web

Tags: java, c++, web

I've been writing some console applications in c++ for working with audio for a little while now and I'm interested in running them on a website. Most of my programs are quite resource-hungry, however, some with execution times of up to 5-10 min, reading and writing several gigabytes to and from disk, and requiring several gigabytes of memory. I've done a few simple php-mysql pages before, but nothing like this, so before i get my hopes up and dive into learning how to get an application running on a website, i figure i should ask a few questions:

1. Is it even feasible to run a program like this on the web? How would performance on a server compare to my PC?
2. Do web hosts typically allow a single user to use this kind of memory?
3. I realize c++ isn't usually the first choice for web programming, but since performance will be critical would it be better than Java?

I know nothing about this, so i'm just trying to get my expectations straight.

Comment: Shared hosting won't cut it, the only way you'll be able to run this kind of program on a web server is if you rent a dedicated server or at the very least a good VPS. Either way this is not cheap for a mere individual.

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion:

1 - The user of your web application is probably not going to wait 5-10 min for a response. You can focus on doing the hard-work on another process and your web app later shows the results to your user in some way.

2 - Yes, they allow, but that costs money. You can see Amazon EC2 and Digital Ocean (cheaper).

3 - The programming language in this case (C++ or Java) is not that important. Focus more on your problem, architecture, deferred tasks, batch processing, etc. That will really make a difference.

Comment: Any idea what the limit on memory usage would be from a typical host at the basic pricing level? Wondering if I even want to try this with some of my smaller apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, the programming language doesn't much matter. It used to be the case that java was slower than C++ i believe, but that gap has closed pretty much as compilers have improved. If you want to run your applications better, try to design them in such a way that they are very efficient. Looking into [Time Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) may help, if you haven't already done so. The better your time complexity, the faster your program.